# Trouble with newClassInstance() in onBeforeWrite()

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to change a pagetype during onBeforeWrite based on another field.

```
if(($this->Status == "Available" || $this->Status == "Sold") && $this->ClassName != "Listing") {
    $this->newClassInstance("Listing");
} elseif( ( $this->Status == "Unavailable" || $this->Status == "Closed") && $this->ClassName != "UnavailableListing")  {
    $this->newClassInstance("UnavailableListing");
}
```

Is this the correct way to use this function?

Comment: Is "UnavailableListing" a subclass of "Listing" ? Does it have any extra fields? If nothing else changes you can try `$this->ClassName = 'UnavailableListing'` to change the class saved to DB.

Comment: If you are just trying to change the PageType of the current page, changing $this->ClassName might actually do the trick.

Comment: Yes UnavailableListing is just a sublass of listing. No new feilds, essentially its subclassed to use different template and so it shows in a differnt list in a ModelAdmin. I was using $this->ClassName = 'UnavailableListing' But the documnetion suggests using newClassInstance()

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still, I think you are missing the

```
parent::onBeforeWrite();
```

call at the end of your function. Hope this helps someone.